# Keeping GWT History Hashes thru Spring Security Login

Tags: gwt, spring-security, url-parameters

I'm retrofitting my application with GWT History support, and I've stumbled on a case where I'm not quite sure what to do. The answer to this question doesn't necessarily have to be GWT-related.

GWT's History support functions by passing around hash tags (i.e. `index.html#token`). Security restrictions require users be logged in prior to actually being able to access `index.html`, so they get sent over to a login page, retaining the token (`login.html#token`). So far, so good. Now the user becomes authenticated and Spring sends them over to `index.html` (the default target) and eliminates the `#token` part of the URL.

How can I force Spring Security to maintain the token and send my newly authenticated user to the page they requested (`index.html#token`)? Since I've already got Spring Security authentication working, I'd prefer to not restructure the way my app handles logins.

Comment: please post the solution as an answer rather than embedding it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a great deal of digging, I found my answer on [Spring's Jira](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1067). As Colin Alworth stated, that token isn't actually part of the request, so Spring Security never sees it server-side, and thus can't use it to determine the final URL. So the approach I used was to append the hash (client-side) to `j_spring_security_check`, making it `j_spring_security_check#token`. Now the token gets passed along just fine, allowing me to have a well-secured app with working tokens.

Thanks for your help Colin, your answer got me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

The server doesn't get to see this token as part of the GET/POST request as you've noted, it is only seen by the browser. Best fix that I've seen for this in the past is for the login page to take note of the current `window.location.hash`, and pass that along, either along with the login form (assuming a redirect will take place that keeps the hash around), or to the server as a login param so it can redirect properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happens, it might help you solve the problem:

1. sending unauthenticated users from index.html to login.html is most
   likely implemented as an HTTP 3xx redirect, and that's why the
   browser keeps the hash fragment (#token).
2. Once they login, spring sends them from login.html to index.html not
   via 3xx redirect so the browser doesn't keep the token.

One solution would be to inject the token into index.html, and pick it up with GWT. Another one is to make login.html -> index.html a 3xx redirect (if spring allows that).